# How to split a PySpark dataframe on column values of a separate dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, azure-synapse

I have a PySpark dataframe which I want to split to two dataframes based on the condition if the value of a column exists in another dataframe.

For exmaple my input dataframe looks like:

```
| Product     | Category        |
| ----------- | ----------------|
| Product A   | Food            |
| Product B   | Food            |
| Product C   | leisure goods.  |
| Product D   | drinks          |
```

The second dataframe is:

```
| Product Categories |
| -------------------|
| Food               |
| leisure goods      |
```

As a result I want to have two dataframes splitted by categories that are in the second dataframe:

```
df1.show()
| Product     | Category        |
| ----------- | ----------------|
| Product A   | Food            |
| Product B   | Food            |
| Product C   | leisure goods.  |

df2.show()
| Product     | Category        |
| ----------- | ----------------|
| Product D   | drinks          |
```

Of course I could do two filter operations on the same dataframe but I would expect a longer runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce PySpark by using the join operation to filter the DataFrame based on the condition that the Category column exists in the second DataFrame.

The below is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("SplitDataFrame").getOrCreate()
data1 = [("Product A", "Food"),
("Product B", "Food"),
("Product C", "leisure goods"),
("Product D", "drinks")]
columns1 = ["Product", "Category"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, columns1)
data2 = [("Food",),
("leisure goods",)]
columns2 = ["Product Categories"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, columns2)
df1_filtered = df1.join(df2, df1["Category"] == df2["Product Categories"], "inner").select(df1["Product"], df1["Category"])
df2_filtered = df1.join(df2, df1["Category"] == df2["Product Categories"], "left_anti").select(df1["Product"], df1["Category"])
df1_filtered.show()
df2_filtered.show()
```

[image]

- I have created two DataFrames df1 and df2
- I have used the join operation to filter df1 based on the condition that the Category column in df1 exists in the Product Categories column in df2. This results in df1_filtered.
- Used a left anti join (left_anti) to filter df1 to get the rows where the Category does not exist in df2. This results in df2_filtered.

By following the above approach you can split the DataFrame into two DataFrames based on the condition
df1_filtered contains rows with categories that exist in df2, while df2_filtered contains rows with categories that do not exist in df2.